# Подключение к Access .mdb через WF C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, access

Пытаюсь выводить данные из базы данных. Думал запрос неправильно на выборку написал, но упростив запрос максимально получаю одну и ту же ошибку (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Ошибка синтаксиса в предложении FROM.")

фото базы данных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
База находится в Debug, названия верно.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace directory
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public static string connectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=DB.mdb;";
        private OleDbConnection myConnection;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectString);

            myConnection.Open();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM Table";
                

            // создаем объект OleDbCommand для выполнения запроса к БД MS Access
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);

            // получаем объект OleDbDataReader для чтения табличного результата запроса SELECT
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            // очищаем listBox1
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            // в цикле построчно читаем ответ от БД
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // выводим данные столбцов текущей строки в listBox1
                listBox1.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString() + " " + reader[1].ToString() + " " + reader[2].ToString() + " " + reader[3].ToString() + " " + reader[4].ToString() + " " + reader[5].ToString() + " ");
            }

            // закрываем OleDbDataReader
            reader.Close();





        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            textBox4.Clear();
            textBox5.Clear();
            textBox6.Clear();
        }


        //Составляем запрос на выборку
        string GetLike()
        {
            string fio, salary, place, notes, year, rank;

            fio = textBox1.Text;
            salary = textBox2.Text;
            place = textBox3.Text;
            notes = textBox4.Text;
            year = textBox5.Text;
            rank = textBox6.Text;

            int i = 0;


            string like = "";

            if (fio != null)
            {
                like += "fio LIKE '" + fio + "%'";
                i++;

            }                

            if (salary != null && i > 0)
            {
                like += " AND salary LIKE '" + salary + "%'";
                i++;
            }               
            else if(salary != null)
            {
                like += " salary LIKE '" + salary + "%'";
                i++;
            }

            if (place != null && i > 0)
            {
                like += " AND place LIKE '" + place + "%'";
                i++;
            }
            else if (place != null)
            {
                like += " place LIKE '" + place + "%'";
                i++;
            }

            if (notes != null && i > 0)
            {
                like += " AND notes LIKE '" + notes + "%'";
                i++;
            }
            else if (notes != null)
            {
                like += " notes LIKE '" + notes + "%'";
                i++;
            }

            if (year != null && i > 0)
            {
                like += " AND data_year LIKE '" + year + "%'";
                i++;
            }
            else if (year != null)
            {
                like += " year LIKE '" + year + "%'";
                i++;
            }

            if (rank != null && i > 0)
            {
                like += " AND rank LIKE '" + rank + "%'";
               
            }
            else if (year != null)
            {
                like += " year rank '" + rank + "%'";
                
            }

            return "where " + like;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Table` - ключевое слово. Возьмите его в кавычки. А лучше переименуйте таблицу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина найдена.
Я использовал ключевое слово "Table" в названии таблицы.
При смене названия программа заработала, как нужно